# Have performers been threatened for performing at inaugurations before?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election

There are [reports](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-4120970/-star-Andrea-Bocelli-backs-singing-Trump-s-inauguration-receiving-death-threats.html) that a famous singer and opera star Andrea Bocelli have pulled out of performing at Trump's inauguration **specifically due to security threats against him** (the pullout was not because he opposes Trump, nor because of commercial worries about fan boycott).

Additionally, more recently, CNN reported that [Jenifer Holliday also had death threats](http://www.cnn.com/2017/01/18/entertainment/jennifer-holliday-trump/) for the same reason (agreeing to perform at Trump inauguration).

**Have performers been physically threatened for performing at inaugurations before?**

Comment: This might be better on history, though i doubt they would want it either.

Comment: The amount of harrassment, threats, and bullying has increased exponentially over the past two presidents' administrations with the mainstreaming of social media, so the answer is probably no. People using their anonymity on the internet to act badly is a bi-partisan problem (as well as people who identify themselves but still still act badly towards others at a physical distance).

Comment: @DrunkenSanta9035768 - or maybe skeptics?

Comment: @indigochild - Skeptics requires a claim to be skeptical of that is lacking from this question so no

Comment: Probably? Entertainers have been threatened throughout history for associating themselves with groups and causes.

Comment: You should change the question to refer to Jenifer Holliday who has admitted retracting because of death threats.

Comment: @blip - death threats to entertainers in America over **performing** (not associating politically)? Examples?

Comment: If you're performing for a political group, people are going to associate you with said group.

Comment: Not sure why you think performing at an inauguration is completely disassociated from any kind of political association.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Trump team, Bocelli offered to perform, and the Trump declined, so that would make the rumors false.

[Andrea Bocelli Won't Be Performing at Trump's Inauguration](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/12/20/arts/andrea-bocelli-wont-be-singing-at-the-trump-inauguration.html)

President Obama, himself, received more death threats, by far, than any president in recent memory. However, his team tended to downplay, minimize and not talk about that aspect, so it would be difficult to get a handle on whether performers at his inauguration got threats.

Stars often get those kinds of anonymous messages, so how credible and how seriously they get taken, as well as the desire to get political mileage from that kind of information can impact whether it was reported in the news of the day.  So, merely having been threatened, while it probably happened, may not be especially meaningful.  I, myself, have been threatened to be hunted down and shot on Facebook.  That doesn't mean the threat was credible.

The Dixie Chicks got a ton of death threats just for saying they didn't support George W Bush in the Iraq War, so it is more likely than not that other performers have received those kinds of threats, even though it appears that Bocelli either didn't, or, at least, isn't "pulling out" of a performance he was never slated to give in the first place.

Comment: This answer is 100% irrelevant. (1) Dixie Chicks weren't threatened for performing. They were threatened for their openly espoused political views. This is irrelevant to the question; (2) Even if Bocelli pulling out wasn't due to death threats officially, now even CNN reports that  Jenifer Holliday also got death threats. So you can't hand-wave this away as non-issue, in your non-answer.

Comment: How is this answer 'hand-waving it as a non-issue'? Seems you're after a very specific and very narrow answer.

Comment: @user4012 - The foundation of the initial claim was shown to be not true.  No hand-waving is needed for a completely fictitious claim.  Dixie Chicks made their statement at a performance.  They were threatened for what happened at their performance.  My answer states that it is difficult to assess because this is a common thing, and how much attention is paid to this occurrence is variable, depending on the credibility and the motivation of the artists and those reporting.  Not sure how you missed that, unless you weren't actually reading carefully, for some reason.

Comment: @blip - because it says "it didn't happen". Clearly it did (see the edit to the question).

Comment: @user0412 - So you claim it's hand-waving because I responded to the original question instead of edits you were going to make to the question after my answer was posted?  You'll note my user ID is not "Nostradamus."